# Efficient way to get the rank of the min of a vector in R?

Tags: r, optimization, vector, minimum, rank

Is there an efficient way in R to get the rank of the minimum (maximum) of a vector (list) ?

I would have found the minimum using the min function

```
p = min(x)
```

And then searched for the rank of *p* in *x* using a for loop...

A better idea to get advantage of R capabilities ?

Comment: I don't think you know what a rank is. The rank of the minimum is 1 if it is unique. If it is a tie, its rank depends on the tie-breaking rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the index in your vector of the minimum value?

There is a function for this, `which.min`, e.g

```
which.min(c(15, 1, 5))
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `order` gives you the order in which you need to put your vector if you want to order it.
so, if `x` is your vector,
`order(x)[1]` gives you the index of the `min` and
`order(x)[length(x)]` (or `order(x, decreasing=T)[1]`) gives you the index of the `max`.

**example**

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10)
x
# [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774  1.71506499  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.68685285
#[10] -0.44566197

# Now, compute the vector of ordered indices with order
ord_x <- order(x)

# get the index of the min
ord_x[1]
#[1] 8

# get the index of the max
ord_x[length(ord_x)]
#[1] 6

# you can check that you have the right indices:
x[8]==min(x)
#[1] TRUE
x[6]==max(x)
#[1] TRUE
```